# Does restarting Yún configuration mess up Arduino or its SD card?

Tags: arduino-yun, sd-card, linux

I noticed something odd recently - a Yún, that was working previously, wouldn't connect.

After logging in to the web setup, setting the access point and password (which hadn't changed), and save & restart, it connected. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work, and after ssh into it, I find I cannot `ls /mnt/sd/` or `sda1`. It just sits there, requiring Ctrl+C, and gives no output.

Did I reset the Arduino or Linux somehow by setting up access point again, or could my SD card be broken after months of heavy logging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your SD card has likely failed. Try connecting it to a computer with an SD card reader. If it works at all, back it up immediately if you have files you wish to keep. Then try reading and writing files on it. Also if you have a spare SD card, try to use that in the Yun after setting it up appropriately. That should help narrow down the cause to either the Yun or the SD card.

Comment: It could also simply be SD card corruption. This can easily happen if a file is being written to and the Yun looses power, or can happen from being force reset while in a stuck state.

Comment: Good guess, actually it looks like the ls command hangs when  there are >11000 files in the root of the card - after removing them and trying again it works.